# Comparing source code

Tags: ajax, jsf

I am a newbie in JSF.I am creating a simple page with a checkbox and a readonly field.When I deploy to weblogic server ,I get what is expected output.
Now I have put autosubmit property on checkbox and partialtrigger propery on the other readonly field.My readonly field changes as expected on changing the state
of checkbox.I was curious to find out what Ajax code has been put in finally rendered page when i declare auto submit property to true.Basically I want to know
what is the html and ajax(javascript) code difference between the case when auto submit property is enabled and disabled.Is there any tool which can compare two source codes?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Being able to see the exact difference in code may be difficult as the associated Javascript files for your JSF component toolkit have probably been [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29), however you should at least be able to see the difference in the Javascript event declarations on the generated `input` element.

A tool like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) is the best choice as it gives you the ability to highlight DOM elements and view their corresponding styles, attributes, and events.  It doubles as an excellent Javascript debugger as well, allowing you to place breakpoints in JS code so that you can walk through the execution of what is happening on each click event.

When `autoSubmit` is false, there is likely no Javascript event being triggered.  When it is true however, there is likely an `onclick` event being triggered that is formulating an Ajax request.  You might have a hard time figuring out what is happening because it is minified, however it is more than likely making such a call.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/js-api/symbols/jsf.ajax.html